# How to route and expand dataframe data based on complex criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python Pandas Dataframes.

Hello, I'm trying to put together a complicated routing system and, despite my best efforts, I cannot put this together. There's a set a default routing rules that decide how rows of data are routed `From` and `To`. But the default rules can be overriden by numbers entered into the `From` and `To` columns. The numbers correspond to `From_Names` and `To_Names`. How do I achieve the result at the bottom? Thank you for all your help.

**Default Routing Rules (Only apply if no number is in "From" or "To" Column of Sample Data)**

| Rules | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | All From_Names | All To_Names |
| 2 | All From_Names | All To_Names with G = "E" |
| 3 | All From_Names | All To_Names with G != "E" |
| 4 | One From_Names | All To_Names |
| 5 | One From_Names | All To_Names with G = "E" |
| 6 | One From_Names | All To_Names with G != "E" |
| 7 | All From_Names | All To_Names |
| 8 | All From_Names | All To_Names with G = "E" |
| 9 | All From_Names | All To_Names with G != "E" |
| 10 | One From_Names | All To_Names |
| 11 | One From_Names | All To_Names with G = "E" |
| 12 | One From_Names | All To_Names with G != "E" |

| From_Names |
| --- |
| Adams |
| Baker |
| Clark |
| Davis |
| Evans |

| To_Names | G |
| --- | --- |
| Irwin Enterprises | E |
| Jones | F |
| Klein | M |
| Lopez, Inc. | E |
| Mason | M |

**This is the dataframe I want to change:**

| From | To | Rule |
| --- | --- | --- |
| None | None | 9 |
| None | 1 | 9 |
| 2,3,4 | 3,4,5 | 3 |
| 2 | None | 4 |

**This is the result I am trying to achieve:**

| From | To | Rule |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adams | Jones | 9 |
| Adams | Klein | 9 |
| Adams | Mason | 9 |
| Baker | Jones | 9 |
| Baker | Klein | 9 |
| Baker | Mason | 9 |
| Clark | Jones | 9 |
| Clark | Klein | 9 |
| Clark | Mason | 9 |
| Davis | Jones | 9 |
| Davis | Klein | 9 |
| Davis | Mason | 9 |
| Evans | Jones | 9 |
| Evans | Klein | 9 |
| Evans | Mason | 9 |
| Adams | Irwin Enterprises | 9 |
| Adams | Jones | 9 |
| Adams | Klein | 9 |
| Adams | Lopez, Inc. | 9 |
| Adams | Mason | 9 |
| Baker | Irwin Enterprises | 9 |
| Baker | Jones | 9 |
| Baker | Klein | 9 |
| Baker | Lopez, Inc. | 9 |
| Baker | Mason | 9 |
| Clark | Irwin Enterprises | 9 |
| Clark | Jones | 9 |
| Clark | Klein | 9 |
| Clark | Lopez, Inc. | 9 |
| Clark | Mason | 9 |
| Davis | Irwin Enterprises | 9 |
| Davis | Jones | 9 |
| Davis | Klein | 9 |
| Davis | Lopez, Inc. | 9 |
| Davis | Mason | 9 |
| Evans | Irwin Enterprises | 9 |
| Evans | Jones | 9 |
| Evans | Klein | 9 |
| Evans | Lopez, Inc. | 9 |
| Evans | Mason | 9 |
| Baker | Klein | 3 |
| Baker | Lopez, Inc. | 3 |
| Baker | Mason | 3 |
| Clark | Klein | 3 |
| Clark | Lopez, Inc. | 3 |
| Clark | Mason | 3 |
| Davis | Klein | 3 |
| Davis | Lopez, Inc. | 3 |
| Davis | Mason | 3 |
| Baker | Irwin Enterprises | 4 |
| Baker | Jones | 4 |
| Baker | Klein | 4 |
| Baker | Lopez, Inc. | 4 |
| Baker | Mason | 4 |

Here's code I've tried so far. I did not want to include it in my question because it's pretty bad and does not work properly:

```
 # Default Rules for Routing Discovery
# 1 = Once Per Case
# 2 = Every Set
Rules = {
    #  From                     To                       Frequency
    1: [PlaintiffsTbl['Name'].values,  DefendantsTbl['Name'],   1],
    2: [PlaintiffsTbl['Name'],  EDefendantsTbl['Name'],  1],
    3: [PlaintiffsTbl['Name'],  IDefendantsTbl['Name'],  1],
    4: [1,                      DefendantsTbl['Name'],   1],
    5: [1,                      EDefendantsTbl['Name'],  1],
    6: [1,                      IDefendantsTbl['Name'],  1],
    7: [PlaintiffsTbl['Name'],  DefendantsTbl['Name'],   2],
    8: [PlaintiffsTbl['Name'],  EDefendantsTbl['Name'],  2],
    9: [PlaintiffsTbl['Name'],  IDefendantsTbl['Name'],  2],
    10:[1,                      DefendantsTbl['Name'],   2],
    11:[1,                      EDefendantsTbl['Name'],  2],
    12:[1,                      IDefendantsTbl['Name'],  2]
}
FromConditions = [

    ((DT['From_'].isnull()) & (DT['Rule'].isin([1,2,3,7,8,9]))),

]

FromChoices = [
    ', '.join(PlaintiffsTbl['Name'].values),
]

DT['From_'] = np.select(FromConditions, FromChoices, default=DT['From_'])

# Split comma-separated numbers in From_ and To_ into separate rows
DT = DT.assign(To_=DT['To_'].str.split(',')).explode('To_').reset_index(drop=True)
DT = DT.assign(From_=DT['From_'].str.split(',')).explode('From_').reset_index(drop=True)

# Map numbers to Plaintiff and Defendant Names
DT['From_'] = pd.to_numeric(DT['From_'], errors='coerce').sub(1).map(PlaintiffsTbl['Name'])
DT['To_'] = pd.to_numeric(DT['To_'], errors='coerce').sub(1).map(DefendantsTbl['Name'])


lst = [4,5,6,10,11,12]
m = DT['Rule'].isin(lst)
DT.loc[m, 'From_'] = (PlaintiffsTbl['Name'].tolist() * (m.sum()//len(PlaintiffsTbl['Name']) + 1))[:m.sum()]
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have tried ?

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that does most of what you want:

```py
def map_names(row):
  if row['From'] is None:
    rule = rules.loc[row['Rule']]['From']
    out_from = parse_rule(data, row['Rule'])
  else:
    out_from = pd.Series(row['From']).map(from_names)
  if row['To'] is None:
    rule = rules.loc[row['Rule']]['To']
    out_to = parse_rule(data, row['Rule'])
  else:
    out_to = pd.Series(row['To']).map(to_names['To name']) # if to_names contains more than one column
  return {'From': out_from, 'To': out_to, 'Rule': row['Rule']}

  pd.DataFrame(data.apply(map_names, axis=1)).explode('From').explode('To')
```

The only part I missed out is the parsing of the rule from a string to an actual list of names. How you implement it really depends on how rich you need this language to be.

But otherwise, the flow goes as follows:

- Replace each From/To value with a corresponding list of names (either by mapping each integer to the corresponding row in the from/to names dataframe or by querying the rule table)
- As a result you get a dataframe where both from and to columns contain lists of names (as strings, not ints), which you just need to explode to have individual rows for all the different combinations.

Your `parse_rule` could look like this:

```py
def parse_rule(data, rule):
  source = [to_names if 'To_names' in rule else from_names]
  if 'with' in rule:
    source = source.query(rule.split('with ')[-1])
  if 'All' in rule:
    return source.tolist()
  return source.tolist()[:1]
```